# Why is this function being called twice in nextjs react app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to make these radio button as changing the state only when the state is "undefined" to a "type" value which is [3 | 5 | 7] and if you click again on the same button then the  state should change to "undefined". the "handleGrid" function handling this logic as well as updating the state, the function is in the code below, however it not function as expected I don't know why but when I
changed the "handleGrid" function just to check what it is doing by changing it to a logging function stated below the original code I encountered that it is running twice that is when the state value is not same  as the type its logs "NO" it outputs it twice. Why is it rendering twice? Why is the original function not working as it should according to me. Also I have changed { reactStrictMode: false } in the next.config.js.

> original code

```
"use client";

import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { GameContext } from "@/context/GameContext";

const GridSelection = ({ className }: { className?: string }) => {
  const gameContext = useContext(GameContext);
  const { setGridType, gridType }: any = gameContext;

  const handleGrid = (type: 3 | 5 | 7): void => {
    if (type === gridType) {
      setGridType(undefined);
    } else {
      setGridType(type);
    }
  };

  return (
    <fieldset className="text-4xl border-solid border-yellow-500 border-t-2 w-[80%] container mx-auto flex justify-between items-center text-center border-b-2">
      <legend className="pr-4 mb-3">Select Grid</legend>

      <div
        className="mb-4 w-full"
        onClick={() => {
          handleGrid(3);
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="grid"
          id="3"
          value={gridType}
          className="hidden peer"
        />
        <label
          htmlFor="3"
          className="p-1 peer-checked:border-yellow-500 peer-checked:border-solid peer-checked:border-2 peer-checked:rounded-md peer-checked:text-yellow-500 border-gray-700 border-solid border-2 rounded-md transition-colors text-gray-700"
        >
          3
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4 w-full" onClick={() => handleGrid(5)}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="grid"
          id="5"
          value={gridType}
          className="hidden peer"
        />
        <label
          htmlFor="5"
          className="p-1 peer-checked:border-yellow-500 peer-checked:border-solid peer-checked:border-2 peer-checked:rounded-md peer-checked:text-yellow-500 border-gray-700 border-solid border-2 rounded-md transition-colors text-gray-700"
        >
          5
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4 w-full" onClick={() => handleGrid(7)}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="grid"
          id="7"
          value={gridType}
          className="hidden peer"
        />
        <label
          htmlFor="7"
          className="p-1 peer-checked:border-yellow-500 peer-checked:border-solid peer-checked:border-2 peer-checked:rounded-md peer-checked:text-yellow-500 border-gray-700 border-solid border-2 rounded-md transition-colors text-gray-700"
        >
          7
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  );
};

export default GridSelection;`

> handleGrid logging code

`const handleGrid = (type: 3 | 5 | 7): void => {
    console.log(type);
    console.log(gridType);
    if (type === gridType) {
      console.log(type, "--", gridType);
      // setGridType(undefined);
    } else {
      console.log("No");
      setGridType(type);
    }
  };
```

> Output

```
GridSelection.tsx:11 3
GridSelection.tsx:12 undefined
GridSelection.tsx:17 No

GridSelection.tsx:11 3
GridSelection.tsx:12 3
GridSelection.tsx:14 3 '--' 3

GridSelection.tsx:11 5
GridSelection.tsx:12 3
GridSelection.tsx:17 No

GridSelection.tsx:11 5
GridSelection.tsx:12 5
GridSelection.tsx:14 5 '--' 5

GridSelection.tsx:11 7
GridSelection.tsx:12 5
GridSelection.tsx:17 No

GridSelection.tsx:11 7
GridSelection.tsx:12 7
GridSelection.tsx:14 7 '--' 7
```

in one call it should prove output of line 11,12,14 or 11,12,17 but it runs twice and gives output of lines 11,12,14&11,12,17 combined